# Vim Plugin NERDTree Dynamic Bookmarks Based on Environment Variables

Tags: bash, vim, sed, module, nerdtree

I love to use NERDTree bookmarks feature, but with the current software I am developing, there are several actively developed versions I switch between. I've picked up using the modules system to deal with setting environment variables and compilers, and I am wondering if I can have my modules edit my ~/.NERDTreeBookMarks paths based on an environment variable.

Is there a *clean* way to do this other than have a script search and replace text in my ~/.NERDTreeBookMarks file based on certain environment variables?

Comment: using a `ln -fs source target` based on your ENV variable content could not solve your problem instead ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to instead use `$CDPATH`, set it up in your bashrc / zshrc and then add this to your vimrc :

```
let &cdpath = ',' . substitute(substitute($CDPATH, '[, ]', '\\\0', 'g'), ':', ',', 'g')
```

Then you don't need any bookmarks, you can simply `:cd dir` and will work as long as the dir is in a dir within the cdpath or the current working directory.

Comment: This would allow for me to set a "bookmark" to one directory, correct? I have several files that I bookmark that are spread throughout the codes directories. It's just a fast way to start working on a particular version. I want to just load the module, open vim, and open 5-6 tabs of the files I'm looking at.

Comment: Ah sorry. I did not know about CDPATH. I read about it and tried it out. This is an alternative solutions, but I would argue this is not a particularly clean solution. Editing my cdpath to include these directories will render tab completion useless in the terminal session (this is a very large collaborative project). If we are considering alternative solutions, I'd say the overall goal is to be able to switch between versions and open all the relevant files in vim tabs with the fewest keystrokes. Perhaps I should look into tmux, and keep many sessions running.